# Changes to the advanced developer certification

Tags: discussion, certification

Just wondering if anybody has more information about the changes to the advanced developer certification. On their [website](http://certification.salesforce.com/schedules#completing-programming-assignment) it says:

> We are improving the Advanced Developer program. Stay tuned for
>   details coming this summer!

I'm particular interested in the programming assigment schedules, as I would like to register for it. Do I need to follow or subscribe to something in order to reserve a place ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a beta program that's currently getting close towards the end. Existing certification holders received an email to register for the new certification exams:

1. Salesforce Certified App Builder
2. Salesforce Certified Platform Developer I
3. Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II

The Platform Developer II is aiming to replace the current Advanced Developer DEV501.

Many of us got rejected as I believe this was "first-in-first-served" type of registration. However, a couple of weeks later I got an acceptance email for "Salesforce Certified Platform Developer II" saying that I have to register within 2 days and take the exam within a couple of weeks. "If you fail to register or cancel, another candidate will be chosen instead" (that's how I got in I reckon).

**Why is there a beta program?**

Salesforce is evaluating the responses from the candidates who completed the beta exams so that they're able to finalise the content as well as set the passing score based on that. As far as I know, this is only valid for the multiple choice part of the exam. Nothing has been mentioned in terms of the assignment.

Based on the multiple choice content, I could say that it was an in-depth DEV501.

If you can still register for the current DEV501, it would be definitely easier than the Platform Developer II. Although, I'm not sure whether the current DEV501 holders will automatically get the Platform Developer II credential. So, if you're keen to get the new credentials, I'd recommend for you to wait another couple of months before these new certs are generally available.

Comment: I was able to able register for the advanced developer and passed the exam, does that mean that it will be invalidated and replaced by the new exam ? I guess I have to wait and see

Comment: I think you should contact support to double check

Comment: I've found this website for anyone who might be interested: http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/FAQ-New-App-Builder-and-Platform-Developer-Credentials

Comment: not official: I believe there will be transition exams for current developer & advanced developer certification holders.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Based on what I've seen and heard I imagine that will be the case for Advanced Developer at least. I'm not sure about Developer. Again, not offical.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the paths forward if you have passed the Advanced Developer exam - http://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/success-services/developer-certification-in-progress.jsp